# Interpret heteroskedasticity plot in R

Tags: r, probability, data-visualization, interpretation, heteroscedasticity

Consider a linear probability model (LPM) where the $Y_i$ is a dummy variable.

To test the presence of heteroskedasticity in our data, I executed the following code:

```
plot(y = LPM$residuals^2, x = LPM$fitted.values,
     ylab = "Squared residuals", xlab = "estimated probabilities")
```

But how am I supposed to interpret the graphic that results?

Comment: If you have a linear probability model, doesn't there have to be heteroscedasticity?